# .Net Core VS2015, Unable to load DLL 'git2-785d8c4': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, libgit2sharp

I am working on .Net Core and trying to migrate the >net 4.5 application into .Net core. During this process, i am finding the following error when trying to access git .dll

following is my Project.json:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Data": "1.0.0-*",
        "NLog": "4.3.5",
        "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9",
        "LibGit2Sharp": "0.22.0",
        "RestSharp": "105.2.3",
        "Unofficial.Ionic.Zip": "1.9.1.8"
      }
    }
```

and here i receives and error on below line of code.

```
if (Repository.IsValid(basePath) == false)
```

Namespaces are included:

```
using LibGit2Sharp;
using LibGit2Sharp.Handlers;
```

error message is:

> Unable to load DLL 'git2-785d8c4': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

i want to know if there is any other method through which i can use this functionality in .Net Core.

Comment: You can run [fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) to figure out where it looks for that dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Beginning with the August 3rd build of LibGit2Sharp ([LibGit2Sharp 0.23.0-pre20160803182831](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp/0.23.0-pre20160803182831)), LibGit2Sharp now supports both regular .NET 4.5 projects (those using `.csproj`-based solutions) and new-style `project.json`-based solutions (like introduced in .NET Core).

Note that LibGit2Sharp still does not support .NET Core, only the new project structure.  Please see https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/1318 for updates.

Comment: He is targeting `net451`

Comment: @Pawel: "I am working on .Net Core and trying to migrate the >net 4.5 application into .Net core"...  What am I not understanding?

Comment: @Pawel : I am targeting net451 but in .net core. My project does not contains dlls or bin folder. with these restrictions, i need to use LibGit2Sharp.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - he is migrating a .NET 4.5 app to a .NET Core app targeting net451.

Comment: @SalmanTariqLone - if this doesn't work because of the native dependencies you could copy them manually in the postpublish step.

Comment: Right, and we don't support that yet.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I have found a project on GitHub, https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp what do you say if i try to convert this project into .net core. Will it work?

Comment: @Pawel thanks for the help i will try your suggestion too.

Comment: Not entirely sure what was here to get downvoted, but please enjoy a new status update for your downvoting pleasures.

Answer (score 1):

The LibGit2Sharp package depends on the LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries package. Since that's a [native package](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/support-for-native-projects), it uses an MSBuild file to copy the native library to the output directory.

.Net Core CLI does not use MSBuild, and I believe as a consequence of that, it does not support MSBuild-based native packages.

If you want to use the LibGit2Sharp package with .Net Core CLI, I believe you will have to wait: the next version of .Net Core CLI (planned for fall 2016) will use MSBuild, so it's possible it will just start working. Alternatively, the authors of LibGit2Sharp might release a compatible package in the future.

Comment: You can use packages with native dependencies in .NET Core. They need to follow certain structure but if they do cli know what bits to copy when you publish your app. I wrote a post on that some time ago: https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/. It's talking about dnx and now loading dlls works a bit differently but the structure of the packages with native dependencies is the same. Also, you could use postpublish/postcompile scripts to copy native dependencies if this is the only problem.